# How to pass Job parameters to iteam processor using anotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

i am using spring batch and i have configured using annotation . Here is my question . how to set and get job parameters in to item process class using annotations .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class DataItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

    private String myParam;

    public DataItemProcessor(String myParam) {
       this.myParam = myParam;
    }

    public OutPutData process(final InputData inputData) throws Exception {

        // Use myParam
    }

}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor<Object, Object> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[myParam]}") String myParam) {
    return new DataItemProcessor(myParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the bean scope to `step` scope and use `@Value` to pass the jobParameter:

```
@Bean @StepScope
public YourProcessor yourProcessor(@Value("#{jobParameters[yourParam]}") Long yourParam) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code sample . 
I am using spring MVC . so from controller i am calling jobLauncher and in job launcher i am passing job parameters like below

JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("fileName", "xxxx.txt").toJobParameters();
stasrtjob = jobLauncher.run(job,jobParameters);

and here is my item processor

public class DataItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

public OutPutData process(final InputData inputData) throws Exception {

```
    // i want to get job Parameters here ????
```

}

}

Comment: You don't put an answer, you update your question. And what's a problem  to create a `ItemProcessor` bean definition that has this as a parameter: `@Value("#{jobParameters[yourParam]}") Long yourParam` and to pass it as an argument when you instantiate your `ItemProcessor` implementation?